# How to use natural sort with Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, natural-sort

I have a table column that I want to order on. The problem is that the column value contains both numbers and text. For example, the result is now ordered like this.

```
1. group one
10. group ten
11. group eleven
2. group two
```

But I'd like the result to be ordered naturally, like this

```
1. group one
2. group two
10. group ten
11. group eleven
```

When looking at the Spring configuration I can't seem to find an option that allows you to do this. I use the Spring Pageable class to set my order field and direction, with an additional use of JPA specifications. The method itself returns a Page with the first 20 results by default.

I don't believe that Oracle supports Natural ordering out of the box so I have a stored procedure for that. Running the query using this procedure I get the desired result.

```
select ... from group order by NATURALSORT(group.name) asc
```

As you might expect I'd like to use that procedure by wrapping it around every ordered column that contains text. While maintaining to use pageables/pages and specifications. The research I done this far points me to a solution that might include

- Either creating and implementing a custom Specification
- Or extending the SimpleJpaRepository to change the way the Sort object is transformed.

But I didn't seem to find a method that allows me to set the order using native SQL. The only way I found to set the order was by calling `orderBy` and including an `Order` object.

So in general.

1. Is there a way to globally enable natural ordering when using Spring Data Jpa, hibernate and the Oracle database
2. If not, how can I wrap a single `order by column` with my stored procedure while still being able to use the `Page findAll(Pageable, Specifications)` method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging into the source code of both Spring JPA and Hibernate I managed to find a solution to my problem. I'm pretty sure this isn't a nice way to solve it, but it's the only one I could find.

I ended up implementing a wrapper for the 'order by' part of the query by extending the `SingularAttributePath` class. This class has a render method that generates the string which gets inserted into the actual query. My implementation looks like this

```
@Override
public String render(RenderingContext renderingContext) {
  String render = super.render(renderingContext);
  render = "MYPACKAGE.NSORT(" + render + ")";
  return render;
}
```

Next I extended the Order conversion functionality in the SimpleJpaRepository class. By default this is done by calling `QueryUtils.toOrders(sort, root, builder)`. But since the method calling it was impossible to override I ended up calling the `toOrder` method myself and altering the result to my liking.

This means replacing all orders in the result by my custom implementation of the `SingularAttributePath` class. As an extra I extended the `Sort` class which is used by the `Pageable` class to have control over what gets wrapped and what doesn't (called NaturalOrder). But I'll get to that in a second. My implementation looks close to this (some checks are left out)

```
// Call the original method to convert the orders
List<Order> orders = QueryUtils.toOrders(sort, root, builder);
for (Order order : orders) {
  // Fetch the original order object from the sort for comparing
  SingularAttributePath orderExpression = (SingularAttributePath) order.getExpression();
  Sort.Order originalOrder = sort.getOrderFor(orderExpression.getAttribute().getName());
  // Check if the original order object is instantiated from my custom order class
  // Also check if the the order should be natural
  if (originalOrder instanceof NaturalSort.NaturalOrderm && ((NaturalSort.NaturalOrder) originalOrder).isNatural()){
    // replace the order with the custom class
    Order newOrder = new OrderImpl(new NaturalSingularAttributePathImpl(builder, expression.getJavaType(), expression.getPathSource(), expression.getAttribute()));
    resultList.add(newOrder);
  }else{
    resultList.add(order);
  }
}
return resultList;
```

The return list then gets added to the query by calling `query.orderBy(resultlist)`. That's it for the back-end.

In order to control the wrap condition I also extended the `Sort` class used by the `Pageable` (mentioned this a few lines back). The only functionality I wanted to add was to have 4 types in the Direction enum.

- ASC (default ascending)
- DESC (default descending)
- NASC (normal ascending)
- NDESC (normal descending)

The last two values only act as placeholders. They set the `isNatural` boolean (variable of the extended `Order` class) which gets used in the condition. At the time they are converted to query they are mapped back to their default variants.

```
public Direction getNativeDirection() {
  if (this == NaturalDirection.NASC)
    return Direction.ASC;
  if (this == NaturalDirection.NDESC)
    return Direction.DESC;
  return Direction.fromString(String.valueOf(this));
}
```

Lastly I replaced the `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` used by the `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. The only thing this does is creating instances of my `NaturalSort` class and passing them into the Pageable object , instead of the default `Sort` class.

In the end I'am able to call the same REST endpoint, while the result differs in the way it's sorted.

```
Default Sorting
/api/v1/items?page=0&size=20&sort=name,asc
Natural Sorting
/api/v1/items?page=0&size=20&sort=name,nasc
```

I hope this solution can help those who have the same or a derived problem regarding natural sort and spring JPA. If you have any question or improvements ,please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any such feature. You could however store the numbers in a separate column, and then order by that column, which should give a better sorting performance as an additional benefit.

Comment: That's not really an option as the name is set by the user. So I have no influence on the contents of that information.

Comment: Is there a way to add native SQL to the generated query from the findAll method?

Comment: @RobinHermans So, there is no predefined format of the entered text? Meaning, that user can enter _"This is 2nd group"_ and it has to come before _"This is 10th group"_ in the sorting order?

Comment: Yes. The kind of ordering you get in the Windows explorer

Comment: @RobinHermans Sorry, I don't know of anything like that that you can utilize in this case.